# Debugging Dart in Dartium - Breakpoint Keyword?

Tags: dart, dartium

When debugging Javascript in the Chrome Dev Tools, using the reserved keyword 'debugger' results in a break point hitting when the Dev Tools are open. Is there an equivalent for debugging dart code in Dartium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Dart SDK 1.11.0 there is a [`debugger`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:developer#id_debugger) function in the new [`dart:developer`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:developer) library to trigger a breakpoint via code. You can pass an optional condition with the `when` parameter and provide and optional message.

```
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  debugger();
  print('Not reached when a debugger is attached till the execution is continued');
}
```

If compiled to JavaScript, the `debugger` keyword is used.